# Class as a parametr when counting instances of classes

Tags: java, class, parameters, counting, instances

I have class Counter with a method add which will count instances of any classes when creating but I get "The method add(Class) in the type Counter is not applicable for the arguments (MyClass)" How can I fix it? What should I type instead of `Class<?> c`?

```
public class Counter
{
    static Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static void add(Class<?> c) 
    {
            String name = c.getClass().getSimpleName();
            int count = list.containsKey(name) ? map.get(name) : 0;
            map.put(name, count + 1);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{  
    public MyClass()
    {
        Counter.add(this); 
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain this -> `count instances of any classes when creating`? Add creates an object as well?

Comment: for example when MyClass a = new MyClass(); I will use hashmap to know that MyClass has in this case one instance

Comment: Where is your list? BTW, I wouldn't name a variable of type `Map`, as `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Rohit Jain that it should be `Object`. I however want to suggest parameterized version of `add()` method:

```
public static <T> add(T obj) {
    Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass();
    // your implementation
}
```

Parameterized versions look better.

Comment: Thanks. I was going to do it this way but then though that maybe it should be done differently. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing your `add` method, you should change the constructor for MyClass to this:

```
public MyClass()
{
    Counter.add(this.getClass());
}
```

That way, you can use your `HashMap<Class<?>, Integer>` (or whatever you're using to do the actual counting) like so:

```
if(map.containsKey(c))
{
    map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1));
}
else
{
    map.put(c, 1);
}
```

There is a potential problem with this counter idea: when an object becomes unreachable and gets collected, the counter won't decrease. So your counter will not be able to tell you how many objects you *currently* have, but how many you have created overall.

Comment: I haven't though about decreasing before this. Thank you for your help